# ¿Que error ven en mi codigo?, estoy practicando con los formularios con node y javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy tratando de imprimir en pantalla y en consola un mensaje al introducir valores en dos inputs mediante NodeJS y javascript pero segun la consola tengo un error en la parte `dataString += data`, ¿Podrian ayudarme con eso?

Nota:estoy usando metodo POST en el formulario.

Aquí esta el codigo:

En NodeJS:

```
'use strict'

const http = require('http').createServer(webServer);
const port = 3000;
const fs = require('fs').readFileSync('public/index.html');
const queryString = require('querystring');
const util = require('util');
const dataString = ''; 


function webServer(req, res){
    if(req.method == 'GET'){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.end(fs);
    };

    if(req.method == 'POST'){
        req.on('data', function(data){
            dataString += data
        }).on('end', function(){
            console.log(`los valores que enviaste son: ${dataString}`);
            res.end(`los valores que enviaste son: ${dataString}`);
        });
    };
};

http.listen(port);
```

Contenido de package.json:

```
{
  "name": "form",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Formulario",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "EMIT",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

El HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input type="email" id="userName" placeholder="Username" name="usuario" required>
                <input type="password" id="passWord" placeholder="Password" name="contraseña" required>
                <input type="submit" id="button" value="Send">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes. Quitando la repetición del enunciado, has planteado la pregunta correctamente, ofreciendo un [mcve]. De todos modos te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para ganar tu primera medalla y entender un poco mejor cómo funciona el sitio. Siempre puedes [edit] tus preguntas y respuestas las veces que consideres necesarias

Answer (score 5):

Declaraste una constante:

```
const dataString = '';
```

Y, como su nombre indica, no puedes modificarla a posteriori (*) concatenándole otro string.

Bastaría declararla con

```
let dataString = '';
```

(*) Esto se aplica a ciertos tipos. Si tu variable fuese un Array, un objeto,un Map, un Set... podrías añadirle elementos o llaves, respectivamente.

Comment: amenadiel me funciono a la perfecion, muchisimas gracias!